# how to know which type of secuity realm is used in glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Is there a programmatic way to know what security realm is used in glass-fish server (JDBC , Ldap , file).
**Edit**  i need to know the type of security realm used in my web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to work with `Realm.getRealmNames()`. This method will return you the enumeration of server realms in which you can find the one you want.

Comment: I want to know which realm is used in web.xml. not the realm defined in the server.

Comment: What is this Realm class package, it seems it is not provided by the javaee api . so is glassfish specific, if so which version.

Comment: Class: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.Realm, library: org.glassfish.security:security:3.0